# Get document with sorted nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping: http://pastebin.com/FgtC5aaw (includes sample data)

> http://localhost:9200/databases/database/1

```
{
 "columns": [
   {
     "name": "First column",
     "position": 1
   },
   {
     "name": "Second column",
     "position": 2
   },
   {
     "name": "Third column",
     "position": 3
   }
 ],
 "name": "Database name"
}
```

What I would like to get is the "database" document(s), but each one with columns sorted in descending order by columns.position field, so:

```
{
    "name": "Database name",
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "Third column",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "Second column",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "First column",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using "sort" on "columns.position", but I think it would just sort all "database" documents on it's nested columns.

Is such a result possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance you'll always need to retrieve the columns `nested` object in decreasing order of `columns.position`, you can simply index your database documents with the `columns` list already properly sorted.

If that's not the case, there is a way to sort the nested `columns` list using [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/databases/database/_search -d '{
  "_source": false,            <---- set this to true to get database fields too
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "columns",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": {
          "columns.position": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Which will yield:

```
{
  ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "databases",
      "_type" : "database",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "inner_hits" : {
        "columns" : {
          "hits" : {
            "total" : 3,
            "max_score" : null,
            "hits" : [ {
              "_index" : "databases",
              "_type" : "database",
              "_id" : "1",
              "_nested" : {
                "field" : "columns",
                "offset" : 2
              },
              "_score" : null,
              "_source":{"name":"Third column","position":3},
              "sort" : [ 3 ]
            }, {
              "_index" : "databases",
              "_type" : "database",
              "_id" : "1",
              "_nested" : {
                "field" : "columns",
                "offset" : 1
              },
              "_score" : null,
              "_source":{"name":"Second column","position":2},
              "sort" : [ 2 ]
            }, {
              "_index" : "databases",
              "_type" : "database",
              "_id" : "1",
              "_nested" : {
                "field" : "columns",
                "offset" : 0
              },
              "_score" : null,
              "_source":{"name":"First column","position":1},
              "sort" : [ 1 ]
            } ]
          }
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```